# JCheckBox[x] is null?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcheckbox

I made a new project with just the code, that contains the error:

```java
package benutzerschnittstelle;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;

public class versuch extends JFrame {
  private static JPanel contentPane;
  static JCheckBox[] CheckBox;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          versuch frame = new versuch();
          frame.setVisible(true);

          for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            CheckBox = new JCheckBox[3];
            CheckBox[x] = new JCheckBox("Prüfungsfach");
            CheckBox[x].setBounds(180, (60 + (25 * x)), 120, 21);
            contentPane.add(CheckBox[x]);
          }

          for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            try {
              System.out.println("checkbox " + x
                      + " : " + CheckBox[x].isSelected());
            } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("error at checkbox " + x
                      + " : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public versuch() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
  }
}
```

Since the checkboxes get checked before I even have the opportunity to select them, the output should be:

```
checkbox 0: false
checkbox 1: false
checkbox 2: false
```

but the output is:

```
error at checkbox 0 : Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JCheckBox.isSelected()" because "benutzerschnittstelle.versuch.CheckBoxPruefungsfach[x]" is null
error at checkbox 1 : Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JCheckBox.isSelected()" because "benutzerschnittstelle.versuch.CheckBoxPruefungsfach[x]" is null
checkbox 2 : false
```

If I vary the length of the array, the last checkbox always works as intended and the rest causes errors... why is that? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In this loop:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    CheckBox = new JCheckBox[3];
    CheckBox[x] = new JCheckBox("Prüfungsfach");
    CheckBox[x].setBounds(180, (60 + (25 * x)), 120, 21);
    contentPane.add(CheckBox[x]);
}
```

You are reassigning the array `CheckBox` *inside the loop*. This will override all the values before the current `x`. So in the last iteration, you’ll have reset the boxes at index 0 and 1 to `null`.

Move the initialisation of the array *before* the loop to fix the issue.

`CheckBox` is also a fairly poor name for an array of check box*es*. Use plural names for collections (and by convention variable names in Java start with a lower-case letter: `camelCase`).

Comment: Ok, thanks it's working now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're creating a new array every time the loop runs, as you assign it inside the loop's body

```java
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    CheckBox = new JCheckBox[3];
    CheckBox[x] = new JCheckBox("Prüfungsfach");
    CheckBox[x].setBounds(180, (60 + (25 * x)), 120, 21);
    contentPane.add(CheckBox[x]);
}
```

Moving `CheckBox = new JCheckBox[3];` outside of the loop will prevent you from overwriting this value upon each loop run.

Also, to better distinguish class names from variables, it's good practice to start variables with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now